# expect: how to keep all output?

Tags: expect

BACKGROUND: when local username is not the same as the git username, git will insist on asking for the password even in the presence of ~/.netrc (one can hit Enter and then netrc is used, but this Enter is required).

QUESTION: I need to do git pull passing the password to git, but I want to see whatever git replies on the stdout (and possibly later redirect). I tried

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn /usr/bin/git $argv
expect Password:
send "secret"
```

and it appears to work, but I do not see the git output.

I tried simple

```
puts "$expect_out(buffer)"
```

and fancy

```
while (1) {
  expect {
    eof  {break}
    -re ".*"  {puts "$expect_out(buffer)"}
  }
}
```

and even [fancier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105629/expect-how-to-print-every-output-of-a-spawned-process-to-the-user)

```
while (1) {
  expect {
    -re "(\[^\n]*\)\n" { send_user $expect_out(buffer) }
    eof  {break}
  }
}
```

and a little bit simpler

```
while (1) {
  expect {
    "\n" { send_user $expect_out(buffer) }
    eof  {break}
  }
}
```

and neither prints the git output.

PS. ssh is not an option in this specific case, please do not waste your time talking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "hit enter" after typing the password: `send "secret\r"`

Comment: perfect.  thanks.  one problem: all git output is now printed twice.

Comment: add `log_user 0` to your expect script.